# read HttpContext.Current.Request in EndRequest event

Tags: asp.net

How I can read the output Request (myxmlData) before sending to the client in EndRequest event or other event?

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
  string myxmlData = MyObject.DataXML();

  Response.ContentType = "text/xml";
  Response.Write(myxmlData);
  Response.End();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the easiest way to do what you want is to use ASP.NET Response Filters.  They give you access to the final output before it is sent to the client.

A quick [example of an ASP.NET Response Filter](http://aspnetlibrary.com/articledetails.aspx?article=Use-Response.Filter-to-intercept-your-HTML) should get you started.

Good luck!

Comment: thanks, just found this link, thanks. http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=25339&seqNum=3